# Why is the columns environment wider than the text width?

Tags: beamer

Why does `beamer`'s `columns` environment not respect the overall text width of a slide? That is why I have preferred the standard `minipage` to create multi-column slides with `beamer` for a long time. But maybe I am using the `columns` environment in the wrong way?

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!10!white}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Slide with columns}
Text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line text line.\\[2ex]

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
Column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
Column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text column text
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\vspace{2ex}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
Minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.1\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
Minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text minipage text
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only Till Tantau will be able to tell you why this is the way it is, but the code seems pretty clear that this was a deliberate design choice.

However there are two easy ways to avoid the problem:

- using the `columns` environment with the `onlytextwidth` option
- or globally with the class option of the same name: `\documentclass[onlytextwidth]{beamer}` (or `\beamer@onlytextwidthtrue` for the use in custom theme file etc.) -- this global option needs beamer v3.65 or newer

[image]